# How to refresh the date object in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I've looked through a number of different answers to similar questions and am still struggling. I have a date function which I am using to name a folder in Google Drive (apps script) but the date doesn't update the next day:

```
function todaysDate()
{

var now = new Date();
var year = now.getFullYear().toString();
var month = now.getMonth()+1;
var monthString = month.toString();
if(monthString.length = 1)
{
 monthString = "0"+monthString; 
}
var day = now.getDate().toString();
var currentDate = year+monthString+day; 
return currentDate;

}
```

When I log the currentDate, it is from a couple of days ago and I'm unsure how to get it to be the actual date from today. The code is in a Google Sheet and the file is being saved into the folder e.g. 20190620 if that is useful. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you are looking for?
This would format 20 June 2019 into: 20190620

```
function myFunction() {
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYYMMdd");  
}
```

So the value of `date` would be the timezone of your script. Alternatively you could put a specific timezone in the place of `Session.getScriptTimeZone()`

Comment: Thank you @Matty, do you know if this will update tomorrow and change the date?

Comment: I changed the date on my laptop to tomorrow and the date still says the 20th. I'll try again tomorrow just in case there's some other reason why the date wouldn't update but I'm not sure this will refresh...

Comment: I believe it is whatever timezone is set in your Google Scripts rather than your local device. Give it a go tomorrow and let me know, alternatively you can set a timezone.

Comment: I just tried to code today and it is still on the 21st June. I think that once the variable has been instantiated, it sticks around in the memory but I want it to update to today's date every time the code is run. Any ideas?